# Get Query Model Binding MVC ASP.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using [datatables](http://datatables.net/manual/server-side) to handle the grids in a project im working on.

I  create a server side action to handle the data processing. Rightnow, datatables sends the sorting parameter as e.g. order[1](http://datatables.net/manual/server-side)[asc], where *1* is the column number to order with and *asc* is the direction, how can my HttpGet action binds to this parameter. I successfully binded to the primitive parameters like the start and length but not in this format.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need a custom model binder, that will parse your input and create objects out of that. If you could provide more details on what particular objects you want to create we could impart some more guidance on the specifics.

See the following article for examples: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder